# Número da página em todas as páginas mpdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

Como fazer para que em todas as páginas apareça o número da página no rodapé?
Tenho resumidamente o código abaixo, mas do jeito que está, o número da página só aparece na última página, como fazer pra aparecer em todas as paginas?

```
$mpdf = new mPDF( 
                 '',    // mode - default ''
                 '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
                 0,     // font size - default 0
                 '',    // default font family
                 15,    // margin_left
                 15,    // margin right
                 58,     // margin top
                 60,    // margin bottom
                 6,     // margin header
                 0,     // margin footer
                 'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');   

$footer = "<table width=\"1000\">
                   <tr>
                     <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>";

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);

$mpdf->Output();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu sei que já faz tempo desde que a pergunta foi feita, mas vale observar: *Em documentos de dupla face, você precisa definir declarações diferentes para rodapés e cabeçalhos de páginas pares e ímpares*; *Em documentos simples, defina cabeçalho e rodapé antes de escrever os dados.* Fazendo isso, a numeração fica perfeita.

```
$mpdf = new mPDF( 
                 '',    // mode - default ''
                 '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
                 0,     // font size - default 0
                 '',    // default font family
                 15,    // margin_left
                 15,    // margin right
                 58,     // margin top
                 60,    // margin bottom
                 6,     // margin header
                 0,     // margin footer
                 'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
/* Amostra de conteudo */
$html = '<table class="table-body">';
for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $html.='<tr>
    <td width="30.3%">Forbrug '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="23.1%">Periode '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="10.76%">'.$i.' MB</td>
    <td width="9.28%">Val '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="12.9%" align="right">I alt '.$i.'</td>
    <td width="13.3%" align="right"><b>moms</b> '.$i.'</td>
    </tr>';
}
$html.= '</table>';

$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');   
$footer = "<table width=\"1000\">
<tr>
<td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
</tr>
</table>";
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Fonte: [Headers & Footers](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-2.html)

Comment: porque precisa ser diferente o estilo das paginas impares e pares?

Comment: Editei a resposta. Não muda o estilo (não necessariamente). Na sua pergunta vc está usando o modo `RUNTIME` para definir o rodapé, e essas são as regras da biblioteca pra esse modo. Teste esse código no seu ambiente, @AlexandreMartinsMontebelo. Ele tem 4 páginas e todas são numeradas em ordem sequencial ;)

Comment: entendi, qto ao modo RUNTIME, onde que "Desdeclaro" ele? Não consegui ver isso comparando os codigos.

Comment: Mudando o modo de declarar a variável que define o rodapé. Veja: [Modos de declarar cabeçalhos e rodapés](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/headers-footers.html). Esse aqui seria o modo `NAMED`: [Method 4](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-4.html), que usa `DefHeaderByName()`. Tanto a pergunta quanto a resposta estão usando `RUNTIME HTML` com `SetHTMLFooter()`.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pelas dicas.

Answer (score 0):

eu coloquei esse seu código aqui no meu e está funcionando vê se serve pra vc

```
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

        $mpdf->AddPage('P', // L - landscape, P - portrait
            '', '', '', '',
            10, // margin_left
            10, // margin right
            5, // margin top
            5, // margin bottom
            10, // margin header
            10);
            $footer = "<table width=\"1000\">
                   <tr>
                     <td style='font-size: 18px; padding-bottom: 20px;' align=\"right\">{PAGENO}</td>
                   </tr>
                 </table>";

$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($footer);
    $css = file_get_contents("css/minu.css");
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
```

Comment: continua com o mesmo problema aqui :/